# Dash Won't Show Up / Brings up a blank window. Also glitchy screen

Tags: unity, screen, unity-dash

**I am new to Ubuntu so *be easy on me*.**

I have **recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 13.04** on a **5 year old desktop** and **everything works fine, except the dash button.**

When I click on the dash button it just **blanks out everything behind it** and the **dash doesn’t show up**. I am wondering if there is a fix for this. I want to search for my applications and such but I **cannot get the dash to show up.**

[image]

I also have **one more problem.**

The **top half of my screen is glitchy** and is really annoying. It kind of **flickers**, and I am wondering if this is just a refresh rate problem or what, but I cannot get it to stop.

Comment: What graphics card do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your graphic driver problem. Try proprietary drivers if available.
Open up dash and type "Software & Updates" then go to "Additional Drivers" tab and see if there is proprietary drivers listed, if yes then choose it. After downloading completed, restart your computer.